# cannot find name error Angular2+ and typescript

Tags: angular, import

So I'm trying to extend the functionality of these two components:
https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart/tree/master/projects/ng-orgchart/src/lib/components/orgchart/chart-container
https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart/tree/master/projects/ng-orgchart/src/lib/components/orgchart/chart-node

from a third party lib:

https://github.com/dabeng/ng-orgchart

and I'm running into issues.

I have the lib imported in my home.module.ts like so:

```
import { OrgchartModule } from '@dabeng/ng-orgchart'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [HelloworldSharedModule, CommonModule, OrgchartModule, RouterModule.forChild([HOME_ROUTE])],
```

but in a child directive of my home module, when I try to extend it like so:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[jhiCustomOrgChart]'
})
export class CustomOrgChartDirective {

  constructor(@Host() @Self() @Optional() public hostChart : ChartContainerComponent) {

    const app = (hostChart as any)._app;

    hostChart.zoomHandler = (ev?: Event) => {
      // my custom zoom behavior here
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot find name 'ChartContainerComponent'.
```

The original lib exports those two components, so why am I getting the "can't find  name" error? I'm new to angular2+ and typescript, being formerly an angularJS developer.

Comment: Have you tried just ```import { OrgchartModule } from '@dabeng/ng-orgchart';``` in your parent module or ```app.module.ts```?

Comment: That line is in the parent module:  'home.module.ts'  and in the child directive I'm still getting: " Cannot find name 'ChartContainerComponent' "

Comment: I'm just not understanding why you're trying to import the individual components. They are all included in the module. You're importing the module. Are you able to use them in your templates? You are not able to import them because they weren't declared in the declaration main.d.ts file by the author, but the components are able to be used because they are included in the module...

Comment: I've added to my post. I'm trying to extend the functionality of those components.

Comment: if you downvoted my question before I updated it, can you update your vote? I'm sorry my question wasn't clear at first

Comment: I didn't down vote it - but to your original question: Take a look at ```dabeng-ng-orgchart.ts``` to see what the components are being exported as. It looks like they have aliases.

Comment: can you post a link to that file? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: It's a generated after the library is created, it's not going to be anywhere on the github, but is inside the node_modules at the root of the library after you have installed it. Here's a stackblitz demonstrating the use of it inside app.component.ts: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-orgchart-demo-cqbf6k?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207608/discussion-between-peter-weeks-and-nullptr-t).